# Autohotkey: Auto minimize a program when it loses focus

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, minimize, lost-focus

I am using the following Autohotkey script win Win 10 to auto minimize a program when it loses focus, however it still minimizes the whole window even if I am open a sub menu or a popup options inside that same program. So how can I make respect all child windows from that program? Or any other script that does that.

```
#NoEnv
#Warn
var := true
SetTimer, subroutine, -1
return

subroutine:
WinWaitNotActive, ahk_exe word.exe
sleep, 2000     
if (var) {
    WinMinimize
    SetTimer, subroutine, -1
}
return

!t::SetTimer, subroutine, % (var:=not var) ? -1 : "Off" 
!x::ExitApp ; ALT+X terminates the script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
; autohotkey v1
#NoEnv
#Warn
#Persistent
SetTimer, subroutine, 5000

subroutine()
{
    If WinActive("ahk_class Notepad++")
    {
        ToolTip, "notepad++ active"
    }
    else
    {
        WinMinimize, ahk_class Notepad++
        ToolTip, "notepad++ not active auto minimize after 5 second"
    }
}
```

```
; autohotkey v2
SetTimer "subroutine", 5000

subroutine()
{
    If WinActive("ahk_class Notepad++")
    {
        ToolTip "notepad++ active"
    }
    else
    {
        WinMinimize "ahk_class Notepad++"
        ToolTip "notepad++ not active auto minimize after a while"
    }
}
```